# Changing index of a website based on time of the day

Tags: javascript

I need your help, I have a website with 2 different versions ( day & night ) which are located on two different addresses, let's say : http://yashtest.com ( day ) and http://dark.yashtest.com ( night ).
I don't know if it's something possible with javascript, but I wanted to load these versions based on the time of the day of the user.

EDIT

I tried this, but it reload the page constantly:

I'm new to Javascript, thank you for your patience.

```
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
        if (7 >= currentTime && currentTime > 20) {
                window.location.href = "dark.yashtest.com";
        }
        else {
                window.location.href =  "yashtest.com";
        }
```

Comment: Please share the code which you have attempted.

Comment: Near-duplicates to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358155/changing-background-based-on-time-of-day-using-javascript or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556085/change-text-daily-based-on-day-and-time-of-day  Take any of those answers and replace the DOM manipulation with a window redirect.

Comment: @Yash have `dark.yashtest.com` only direct to `yashtest.com` and `yashtest.com` only direct to `dark.yashtest.com`. This way you will avoid the page constantly directing to itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a condition before directing to make sure the window is not already on the page you want to direct to.

Example:

```
// GET CURRENT TIME
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();

// CHECK DAY OR NIGHT
if (7 >= currentTime || currentTime > 20) {

    // CHECK IF NOT ALREADY ON NIGHT PAGE
    if(!window.location.href.includes("dark")){

        // DIRECT NIGHT
        window.location.href = "dark.yashtest.com";

    }

}else{

    // CHECK IF NOT ALREADY ON DAY PAGE
    if(window.location.href.includes("dark")){

        // DIRECT DAY
        window.location.href =  "yashtest.com";

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still reload the page

Comment: @Yash try it with the changes I made.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried and it doesn't reload the page anymore, but unfortunately it doesn't load the 'night page' when trying to apply it at an earlier time for test

Comment: @Yash did you put the `!` in the front of the condition? I had missed it earlier

Comment: Yes I did, I don't understand what's wrong, I tried to reverse like this and it redirect to the night page whatever the hour :

var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
if (7 >= currentTime && currentTime > 20) {
    if(!window.location.href.includes("yashtest.com")){
        window.location.href = "yashtest.com";
    }
}else{
    if(!window.location.href.includes("dark.yashtest.com")){
        window.location.href =  "dark.yashtest.com";
    }
}

Comment: @Yash maybe try doing a console log of what `window.location.href` is or maybe run `alert(window.location.href)` at the start of your script.

Comment: With alert(window.location.href) the page location is the 'Day page' with your original script, it didn't redirect to the 'Night page' ( when it's night of course )

Comment: @Yash when you say its 'Day page' do you mean the alert contains the url `yashtest.com` exactly?

Comment: Yes that' it, sorry if I'm not clear !

Maybe there is a problem here ? : if (7 >= currentTime && currentTime > 20)

Currently it's 17h here, so I tried like this to test it (7 >= currentTime && currentTime > 17)

Comment: @Yash change the `&&` to `||`

Comment: The alert is still yashtest.com :(

Comment: @Yash try doing an alert for `currentTime`

Comment: I added this to the script for time alert, and the hour is correct :

alert(startTime());
   function startTime(){
     var today = new Date();
     var h = today.getHours();
     var m = today.getMinutes();
     var s = today.getSeconds(); 
     return [ h, m, s ].join(':')
   }

Comment: Well it work now, I don't know why but when I remove the alert and keep the time function, it works ! Thanks a lot for your help @Tony !